# Fail to run overly long DolphinDB scripts with Python API

Tags: python, error-handling, dolphindb

When calling `session.run()` to execute overly long DolphinDB scripts in Python, the following error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: <Exception> in run: Failed to parse the incoming object with I0 error type 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate DolphinDB scripts into a defined module or function view on DolphinDB server, and then call the scripts using `s.run(func, args)` in Python.